# Highstocks - range selector with data grouping with volume based indicators breaks the chart

Tags: highcharts

On Highstocks if I use range selector with data grouping and add to the chart volume based indicators (e.g. OBV) then changing date range by range selector button breaks the chart -

The result:
Volume series and indicator disappear from the chart and in console there is a following error visible:

```
Uncaught Error: Series aapl-volume not found! Check `volumeSeriesID`.
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/72dghy9z/2/

Scenario:

1. Open the demo and add OBV indicator
2. Click on any range selector button

I guess this unresolved error: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18409 could be caused by the same problem.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Hi @TomStack, Yes, the issue looks like a bug in Highcharts. I think that the best will be to report the problem with described steps to reproduce on Highcharts GitHub.

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. I've reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18643